# Appending to PATH in a Windows Docker container

Tags: docker, containers, windows-container

I need to append to the PATH within a Windows Docker container, and I've tried many permutations.

```
ENV PATH=%PATH%;C:\\Foo\\bin
ENV PATH=$PATH;C:\\Foo\\bin
ENV PATH="%PATH%;C:\Foo\bin"
ENV PATH="$PATH;C:\Foo\bin"
RUN "set PATH=%PATH%;C:\Foo\bin"
```

None of these work: they don't evaluate the preexisting PATH variable.

What is the right syntax to append to the PATH? Can I even append to the PATH inside Docker? (I can on similar Linux containers)

Comment: Environment variables which you pass to Docker container are only visible for processes executed by docker executable. They will not be visible machine wide. But if you are ok with that then why not just read this variable during start up and append it PATH variable once inside container instead. Issue with environment variables not visible system wide is here https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/30192

Comment: @GSA, if there is no solution, I'd consider that an answer, too. But I'm surprised that the "Append to the PATH for my container environment" isn't a solved user-story for Windows containers.

Answer (score 67, accepted):

Unfortunately `ENV` won't work, because windows environment variable work a little differently than linux. [more info](https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/30033)

As of now the only way to do this is through `RUN`

But you don't need to create a separate file to do this. This can be done by the following much simpler one line command:

`RUN setx path "%path%;C:\Foo\bin"`

Comment: PS equiv: RUN setx /M PATH $($Env:PATH + ';C:\Foo\bin)

Comment: @JasonCoder - thanks!  Just missing a final single quote before the last paren.

Comment: We tried your solution today, and ran into the trouble that setx did not work but only ENV, as suggested here: https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell-Docker/issues/164 I'm quite puzzled; but we will soon switch to linux containers anyway...

Comment: PS equiv 2: `RUN setx /M PATH \"$Env:PATH;C:\Foo\bin\"`. Spent a couple extra irritating hours *re*-finding out that you need to escape the double quote `\"` in Dockerfile-windows-powershell to have a literal double quote in the command. See https://github.com/StefanScherer/dockerfiles-windows/tree/789fa0b54c0d0263fa9464025cfe12ec2fe0cd6c/quotes. In other words, the above is equivalent to having an interactive powershell session and doing `setx /M PATH "$Env:Path;C:\Foo\bin"`

Comment: Actually, it's a bit more complicated than I initially realized. You may also want to be aware of the three types of environment variable: Machine/System, User, Process. See [this](https://github.com/solstice333/docker-env-var-repro#reliable-ways-for-setting-environment-variables-in-windows-docker-powershell)

Answer (score 13):

You can set environment variables permanently in the container using a powershell script.

Create a powershell script in yout docker context (e.g. setpath.ps1 ) containing this:

```
[Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable("Path", $env:Path + ";C:\Foo\bin", [EnvironmentVariableTarget]::Machine)
```

Add this script to your container dockerfile and RUN the script. Add something like this to your dockerfile:

```
ADD ./setpath.ps1 c:/MyScripts/setpath.ps1
RUN powershell -Command c:\MyScripts\setpath.ps1
```

Comment: This does not work for me. The PATH variable is the same as before, regardless of whether I have this line in my dockerfile. Any ideas?

Comment: This worked for me on a dotnet framework container (4.7.1). Only thing I would add was to get any "RUN powershell..." command to work properly I had to add the ENTRYPOINT ["powershell.exe"] line to the top of the dockerfile after the FROM.

Answer (score 10):

`[Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable` is a good way, but will not work in nanoserver.
The best choice is:

```
RUN setx path '%path%;C:\Foo\bin'
```

Comment: This is giving me `ERROR: The system cannot find registry path specified.` for the image `mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:7.0` ... That image doesn't have powershell ot try the powershell solution. But suggestion of Mark Nguyen, using `USER ContainerAdministrator` and then using the `/M` flag for `setx` does work.

Answer (score 10):

This worked for me:

```
USER ContainerAdministrator
RUN setx /M PATH "%PATH%;C:/your/path"
USER ContainerUser
```

As seen in the .net sdk Dockerfile: https://github.com/dotnet/dotnet-docker/blob/20ea9f045a8eacef3fc33d41d58151d793f0cf36/2.1/sdk/nanoserver-1909/amd64/Dockerfile#L28-L29

Comment: This works for me! Tested on Windows Nano Server 1909

Comment: Awsome, thanks.  Worked on Server 2019 with `mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/framework/sdk:4.7.2` image. Since all my other commands in the dockerfile use escaped backslash as a path separator I modified the command to `RUN "setx /M PATH \"%PATH%;C:\\Program Files\\Git\\bin\""`

Answer (score 2):

Despite all previous answers, I've faced an issue in some environments. Basically on a custom local test environment the setx using the *%PATH%;C:\foo\bar* way works even when the folder has spaces like *C:\Program Files*. That though didn't work when trying it on our production environment.
Checking what Microsoft do when they install the base packages on their own images it turns out a better and more reliable way is to use the command this way:

```
RUN setx /M PATH $(${Env:PATH} + \";${Env:ProgramFiles(x86)}\foo\bar\")
```

This way docker will be able to get the proper paths and properly update the PATH data.

**Edit:**
I've fixed the missing trailing \ in the command, thanks to Robin Ding :)

Comment: Missing \ at the end: ```RUN setx /M PATH $(${Env:PATH} + \";${Env:ProgramFiles(x86)}\foo\bar\")```
Also works with space:
```RUN setx /M PATH $(${Env:PATH} + \";${Env:ProgramFiles(x86)}\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\MSBuild\Current\Bin\")```

Answer (score 0):

The following works for me in nanoserver-1809 (from [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell-Docker/issues/236#issuecomment-498866081)):

```
ENV PATH="$WindowsPATH;C:\Foo\bin"
```

Comment: For me the PATH variable looks like this afterwards: `;C:\Foo\bin`. It seems like you cannot access the current `PATH`/`WindowsPATH` variable within the ENV command.

Answer (score 0):

My answer is similar to mirsik's but has no need for a separate script. Just put this in your Dockerfile

```
RUN $env:PATH = 'C:\Foo\bin;{0}' -f $env:PATH ; \
[Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable('PATH', $env:PATH, [EnvironmentVariableTarget]::Machine)
```

Answer (score 0):

The below commands worked for me in a `Dockerfile` with the base image `mcr.microsoft.com/windows/servercore:ltsc2019`.

(My scenario was to set `Java` in the `PATH`. It works even if there are spaces in the path)

(Make sure to update JAVA_HOME environment variable, with your application/tool)

```
ENV JAVA_HOME="C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-17"

RUN $newPath = ('{0}\bin;{1}' -f $env:JAVA_HOME, $env:PATH); \
     [Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable('PATH', $newPath, [EnvironmentVariableTarget]::Machine)

CMD ["java", "--version"]
```

---

*On a side note, I did get errors like below when trying some of the other answers here (for reasons like - there were spaces in the path, or, Env variable `${Env:ProgramFiles}` was not getting resolved properly, etc.)*

- *The term 'C:\Program' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet.*
- *Unexpected token '\Java\jdk-17\bin' in expression or statement.*

Answer (score 0):

i have used mirsik solution.
My problem was that I had directories with spaces and unknown version numbers.

Ex: `"C:\Program Files\Prog\Vers_*\bin"`

this was the solution for my problem:

1. navigate to the directory and create a symbolic link from the destination folder and put it to a reachable place (C:)

`RUN powershell -Command "cd 'C:\Program Files\Prog\Vers_*\bin';$path = (Get-Location).Path; New-Item -ItemType SymbolicLink -Path 'C:\' -Name 'Prog.lnk' -Target $path"`

2. add the symbolic link to PATH

`RUN setx /M PATH "%PATH%;C:\Prog.lnk\"`

It's not a pretty workflow, but it worked for me....

Answer (score 0):

My solution works. I hope you can be inspired by the example code below where I installed the Gitlab release-cli into my Windows docker image.

```
# escape=`

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/windows/servercore:ltsc2019
SHELL ["powershell", "-Command", "$ErrorActionPreference = 'Stop'; $ProgressPreference = 'SilentlyContinue';"]

# ... # Here you add your other business logic

# Install Gitlab release-cli
ARG RELEASE_CLI_URL="https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/release-cli/-/releases/v0.16.0/downloads/bin/release-cli-windows-amd64.exe"
ARG RELEASE_CLI_LOCATION="C:\GitLab\Release-CLI\bin"
ADD $RELEASE_CLI_URL "$RELEASE_CLI_LOCATION\release-cli.exe"
# Add the path of release-cli.exe to the environment variable PATH in Windows
RUN $NEW_PATH = '{0};{1}' -f $RELEASE_CLI_LOCATION, $env:PATH ; `
    [Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable('PATH', $NEW_PATH, [EnvironmentVariableTarget]::Machine)
```