# How to update path in Windows container for Docker?

Tags: windows, powershell, docker

I am trying to update the path inside my container. I have been everywhere and checked out [several](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42092932/appending-to-path-in-a-windows-docker-container) threads on this and [nothing works](https://forums.docker.com/t/cannot-update-path-variable-in-a-windows-docker-container/30960). So, that's the trick?

```
# escape=`
ARG SDK_VERSION=4.8

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/framework/sdk:${SDK_VERSION}

ENV NODE_VERSION=8.11.2

HEALTHCHECK NONE

RUN Set-ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Scope Process -Force; iex ((New-Object 
System.Net.WebClient).DownloadString('https://chocolatey.org/install.ps1'))

USER ContainerAdministrator

RUN setx /M PATH "%PATH%;C:/Foo/bin"

USER ContainerUser

SHELL ["cmd", "/S", "/C"]

CMD ["powershell.exe", "-NoLogo", "-ExecutionPolicy", "Bypass"]
```

This is the error:

```
PS C:\users\cbongiorno\source> docker build -t mercury:latest -m 4GB -f Dockerfile i18n-tools
Sending build context to Docker daemon  2.057MB
Step 1/10 : ARG SDK_VERSION=4.8
Step 2/10 : FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/framework/sdk:${SDK_VERSION}
 ---> 4a9d58026a2d
Step 7/10 : RUN setx /M PATH "%PATH%;C:/Foo/bin"
 ---> Running in 1caf9e758af2

SUCCESS: Specified value was saved.
C:/Foo/bin : The term 'C:/Foo/bin' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet,
function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or
if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:96
+ ... ogressPreference = 'SilentlyContinue'; setx /M PATH %PATH%;C:/Foo/bin
+                                                                ~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (C:/Foo/bin:String) [], ParentCo
   ntainsErrorRecordException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException

The command 'powershell -Command $ErrorActionPreference = 'Stop'; $ProgressPreference = 'SilentlyContinue'; setx /M PATH "%PATH%;C:/Foo/bin"' returned a non-zero code: 1
```

Answer (score 2):

There are at least two ways to update the `PATH`:

1. Using `setx` as the earlier answer suggests and as is displayed in the golang's [nanoserver-1809/Dockerfile](https://github.com/docker-library/golang/blob/ad65a7b21b2689de3a15334a7db2917a3b9216ec/1.16/windows/nanoserver-1809/Dockerfile). Notice the use of the [USER](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#user) instruction. The `ContainerAdministrator` must be used in order to set the system `PATH`:

   ```
   # PATH isn't actually set in the Docker image, so we have to set it from within the container
   USER ContainerAdministrator
   RUN setx /m PATH "%GOPATH%\bin;C:\go\bin;%PATH%"
   USER ContainerUser
   # doing this first to share cache across versions more aggressively
   ```
2. Using Powershell as displayed in the golang's [windowsservercore-ltsc2016/Dockerfile](https://github.com/docker-library/golang/blob/ad65a7b21b2689de3a15334a7db2917a3b9216ec/1.16/windows/windowsservercore-ltsc2016/Dockerfile)

   ```
   RUN $newPath = ('{0}\bin;C:\go\bin;{1}' -f $env:GOPATH, $env:PATH); \
       Write-Host ('Updating PATH: {0}' -f $newPath); \
       [Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable('PATH', $newPath, [EnvironmentVariableTarget]::Machine);
   # doing this first to share cache across versions more aggressively
   ```

Both ways do work with recent Docker Desktop.

The [ENV](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#env) instruction is [not going to work on Windows](https://forums.docker.com/t/cannot-update-path-variable-in-a-windows-docker-container/30960/4).

Answer (score 1):

This is what I got working, but it doesn't seem ideal:

```
RUN setx /M PATH $($Env:PATH + ';C:\Foo\bin')
```